# Loaders & jquery not working in the livewire pagination

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-livewire

My code is working correctly in the first page, but when I navigate to the second page the loading icons and the jQuery effects not working correctly when I submitting a form.
It's insert the data without showing the loading icon.

my view

```html
<x-livewire.form.buttons.save type="submit" 
                              title="{{ __('buttons.save') }}" 
                              wire:target="form_data.{{ $user->id }}.file" 
                              wire:loading.attr="disabled"
>
    <div wire:target="save({{ $user->id }})" wire:loading.remove>
        {{ __('buttons.save') }}
    </div>

    <div wire:target="save({{ $user->id }})" wire:loading>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
    </div>
    
</x-livewire.form.buttons.save>
```

php

```php
public $page;
public $name = '';
public $badge_number = '';


public $form_data = [];
public $permission_type = [];

protected $queryString = [
    'page',
    'name',
    'badge_number',
];

public function updatingName()
{
    $this->resetPage();
}

public function updatingBadgeNumber(){

    $this->resetPage();
}

public function render()
{
    $name = $this->name;
    $badge_number = $this->badge_number;

    if($name === '' && $badge_number === '')
    {
        $users = User::orderBy('name')
        ->paginate(15);
    }
    else
    {
        $users = User::where('name', 'like', '%' . $name . '%')
        ->where('badge_number', 'like', $badge_number . '%')
        ->orderBy('name')
        ->paginate(15);
    }

    return view('livewire.attendances.daily', [
        'users' => $users,
        'page' => $this->getPage()
    ]);
}
```

Comment: The published code doesn't seem sufficient to give an answer, you should publish the component 
*form.buttons.save* and show/explain the *jquery effects*